# Is there any other way to store data from database, other than using dataset or datatable in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Like the title suggest, I would like to ask, is there any other way to store data from database, other than using dataset or datatable in ASP.NET?

I'm currently using something like this:

```
 Public Function openDataTable(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
    Try
        If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Close()
        con.Open()
        dt = New DataTable
        adap = New SqlDataAdapter(query, con)
        adap.Fill(dt)
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox.Message)
    End Try

    Return dt
End Function

dt = conn.openDataTable("Select * From Employee")
```

It worked fine for me, but I would like to know, is there any other way to do it?

And if there is another way, would someone be so kind as to give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. You can use lots of ways using classes from the [`SqlClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.aspx) namespace, or use libraries that rely on that. You can also use an Object Relational Mapper like NHibernate or Entity Framework. This makes your question too broad to answer. Are you having a specific problem with DataSet / DataTable? What did you research yourself? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I try using another method beside using DataSet/DataTable. My boss said it takes a long time to retrieve data from database if we are using dataset/datatable. So we got a task to looking for another method

Comment: Then try a few ways and benchmark them. Don't forget to profile your queries too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .net framework 3.5 and above you can use linq with entity framework.

Start here:

1. [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)
2. [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

A very good Entity framework Tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B

Introduction to LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397897.aspx

[Getting Started with LINQ in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397910.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could:

1. Run SQL Statements directly
2. Use Linq to SQL
3. Use Entity Framework